# Async/await function not awaiting after creating write stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, pm2, pdfmake

I have a node app that uses express for routing and pdfmake npm for generating a pdf document. On the click of a button, I make an http request that retrieves data from a database, generates a pdf document, and saves to disk. However, my async/await functions only seem to work before I create a write stream using `fs.createWriteStream(path)`. All async/awaits after that seem to be ignored. Also, this only happens on a prod server. When debugging my app locally, **ALL** async/await functions seem to work. Any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Express route:

```
router.patch('/:id(\\d+)/approve', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let id = req.params.id

        const invoice = await db.fetchInvoiceById(id)

        const harvestInvoice = await harvest.getInvoiceById(invoice.harvest_id)

        // generate invoice pdf
        await pdf.generateInvoice(invoice, harvestInvoice)

        res.status(200).json({ id: id })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'something went wrong' })
    }
})
```

Functions:

```
async function SLEEP5() {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('DONE');
    }, 5000);
  });
}

function test(doc, invoicePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(invoicePath)

    writeStream.on("finish", () => { resolve(true) })
    writeStream.on("error", () => { reject(false) })

    doc.pipe(writeStream)
    doc.end()
  })
}

exports.generateInvoice = async function generateInvoice(invoice, harvestInvoice) {
    const invoicePath = `${__dirname}\\invoice_${invoice.number}.pdf`

    let printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts)
    let def = { // pdf defined here }

    // generate invoice PDF
    let doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(def, {})

    await SLEEP5() // THIS IS AWAITED

    await test(doc, invoicePath)

    await SLEEP5() // THIS IS NOT AWAITED FOR SOME REASON
}
```

I am using PM2 to run this node app on an aws ec2 server and Im using version **0.2.4** of pdfmake

Comment: Are you sure that your `test` function gets resolved? The behavior you described could very well correspond to a promise rejection. Also, there is a mismatch (probably a typo) between the function you call in your route (`generateInvoice`) and the exported function (`generateCharterInvoice`)

Comment: `printer.createPdfKitDocument` returns a promise, in master, which version do you use

Comment: I believe the promise resolves because all the contents of the pdf are written to a file and i am able to open/preview the file. Also ive tried `await printer.createPdfKitDocument` and the issue still occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what my issue was. It turns out that I was using **pm2 start appName --watch** to run my app. I was writing the pdf to a directory within the  app. PM2 was detecting a change when the the pdf was being written and would restart the app (because of the **--watch** flag), causing all the issues i was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `printer.createPdfKitDocument(def, {})` does exactly, but

```
let doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(def, {})
await sleep(5)
await writeStreamToFile(doc, invoicePath)
```

certainly looks problematic. If `doc` is not paused at creation, it might run *and finish* while you're still sleeping, and then pipe nothing into your write stream which will never emit a `finish` or `error` event. So remove the `await sleep(5)`, and *immediately* do `doc.pipe(writeStream)` and *immediately* start listening for the events.

If you insist on waiting, either do

```
let doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(def, {})
await Promise.all([
  sleep(5),
  writeStreamToFile(doc, invoicePath),
])
```

or try

```
const doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(def, {})
doc.pause()
await sleep(5)
await writeStreamToFile(doc, invoicePath)
```

(The other explanation of course would be that `createPdfKitDocument` creates a never-ending stream, or errors without emitting an `error` event, etc. that would lead to the promise not being resolved).

Comment: Using `await Promise.all([ sleep(5000), writeStreamToFile(doc, invoicePath) ])` does not work (it is returning before 5 seconds have elapsed). The main issue that i was running into was that the pdf was being malformed because my stream was not piping all the contents (when not using a sleep function)

Comment: @homes It only would return earlier than in 5s if one of the promises rejected.

Comment: @homes "*not piping all the contents when not using a sleep function*" - I can't see how that would happen. If at all, it doesn't pipe all the contents *when* using a sleep function.

Comment: Something strange is happening because this is only occuring when running on a prod server using pm2. When i debug locally in vscode, everything works fine. I even tried running the app locally using pm2, and verything works. If it's any help, my http request is responding with a status of 502.

Comment: 502 could mean anything, you need to get the logs. And you won't get that locally because you're not use a gateway/proxy there - this depends on your production deployment.